# Appending two lists containing numpy array in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to append list `A` from two different iterations containing numpy array. The current and expected outputs are presented.

Iteration 1:

```
import numpy as np

 A=[np.array([[1],
         [2],
         [3]])]
```

Iteration 2:

```
 A=[np.array([[1.3],
         [2.7],
         [3.5]])]
```

```
A=A+A
```

The current output is

```
[array([[1.3],
       [2.7],
       [3.5]]), array([[1.3],
       [2.7],
       [3.5]])]
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]]), array([[1.3],
       [2.7],
       [3.5]])]
```

Comment: so you want lists of arrays?

Comment: Also, `A` cannot reference two different objects simultaneously, name the second one `B`

Comment: After iteration 2 the original value assigned to A has gone forever

Comment: Is there a way to preserve both the values i.e. iteration 1 and 2 using the same reference ```A```?

Comment: @user19862793, why do you need the same reference? Are there not enough letters in the alphabet? :)   There probably exists a better way to do what you are trying to do - without having A reference two different things at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending arrays to the list `A` during each iteration:

```py
A = []

for i in range(10):
    current_array = np.array([[1.3],
                              [2.7],
                              [3.5]])
    A.append(current_array)
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite follow the logic here.

Comment: @user19862793, array `A` includes one more array per each loop. In the end it will contain all the arrays (of all iterations. In my example there are 10 iterations). Is this your goal? (in my example all arrays are same, but you have different arrays every iteration)